# Polymorphic animals speak their name and make a noise

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, inheritance, polymorphism, smalltalk

I'm new to GNU Smalltalk. I'd like to port a script I've written in [Ruby](https://gist.github.com/rtoal/6018426), [Scala](https://gist.github.com/rtoal/d5e3ae7462da87462d92), [CoffeeScript](https://gist.github.com/rtoal/c254a6e2d8c02ae68864), and several others. It's the one I use to try to learn the classic OOP concepts of abstract classes, abstract methods, overriding, dispatch, etc. It goes like this:

1. Define an abstract class `Animal` with a constructor to set the animal's name, a `speak` method to return a string `N says S` where `N` is the name and `S` is the sound the animal makes.
2. Define three concrete subclasses `Horse`, `Cow`, and `Sheep`, each with their own sound-returning string method.
3. Create a horse and sheep and a cow, and make them speak. For the horse and cow, create a variable. For the sheep, call the speak method on an "anonymous" object.

My GNU Smalltalk solution is:

```
Object subclass: Animal [
    | name |
    Animal class >> new: n [^super new init: n]
    init: n [name := n]
    speak [^name, ' says ', self sound]
]

Animal subclass: Horse [
    sound [^'neigh']
]

Animal subclass: Sheep [
    sound [^'baaaa']
]

Animal subclass: Cow [
    sound [^'moooo']
]

h := Horse new: 'CJ'.
h speak displayNl.
c := Cow new: 'Bessie'.
c speak displayNl.
(Sheep new: 'Little Lamb') speak displayNl.
```

I get the expected output but I am unhappy with the solution. I'd appreciate input on:

1. The whole `new` and `init` thing. Is there a way to make it cleaner?
2. I noticed I did not have to override `new` or `init` in my subclasses; did the subclasses *really* inherit `new`? It is a classmethod and I don't know if it is inherited or not.
3. Are we *supposed* to give an implementation of `new`? I had heard this was not a good idea. I know from Ruby that you just define `initialize` and use the built-in `new` to automatically invoke the `initialize` instance method.
4. Is this GNU Smalltalk syntax I got from the GNU tutorial proper or is it an extension of some sort? Should this be written in a proper, "purer" Smalltalk style? I've seen some where there is an `instanceVariables` message.
5. I know Smalltalk has something called `subclassResponsibility`. Is it wise to declare the `sound` method in the `Animal` class (as an abstract method)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Item 1**
Instead of `Animal new: n` use `Animal named: aString` implemented on the class side of Animal as:

```
named: aString
    ^self new name: aString
```

Then in the instance side of the class define

```
name: aString
    name := aString
```

**Item 2**
Yes, `new` is inherited by the subclass. The same happens with all class methods; they are inherited by subclasses.

**Item 3**
You don't have to implement `new`, unless you want to do something special in your class. In most dialects (I haven't checked GNU Smalltalk) `new` will call the instance method `initialize`, which by default does nothing. If you need to initialize you instances, then implement `initialize` as

```
initialize
     super initialize.
     "your specific code"
```

**Item 4**
Can't help on this one but yes, the usual message for creating a subclass includes a keyword for declaring named instance variables.

**Item 5**
You have two options here. (1) You can implement `sound` in Animal as `self subclassResponsibility`. (2) You can implement it with a default value ^`oops`. The first alternative will indicate the programmer extending the hierarchy what method they must to provide in the new subclass. The second will just provide a default sound for the programmer to find out and refine.

---**EDIT**---

A more realistic implementation (meaning, one not intended to test OOP concepts in Smalltalk) would get rid of the `name` instance variable of `Animal`. This is possible because the class name already provides the animal's name. In other words, the instance doesn't need to "remember" its name because its class already knows it. Here is the instance side code

```
name
    ^self class name asLowercase
```

Note that instances of the abstract class `Animal` will now answer the string `'animal'` as their `name`.

With this simplification the instance creation method (class side) `named:` would no longer be required. However, we could tweak its implementation so it answers an instance of the appropriate subclass:

```
named: aString
    | subclass |
    subclass := Animal withAllSubclasses
        detect: [:class | class name asLowercase = aString] ifNone: [self].
    ^subclass new
```

With these changes we no longer need the `name` instance variable and also will be able to create, say an instance of `Horse` evaluating: `Animal named: 'horse'`, etc.

Comment: This is a great answer, and the code did work when I implemented your suggestions. It does, however, introduce `name:` as a "setter" of sorts. I would like the name to be unchangeable after initialization. Is this possible while keeping the lovely `named:` class method?

Comment: Good question. I've updated my answer.

Comment: In GNU Smalltalk, `initialize` does not run automatically on object creation.